# if array key value is duplicate

Tags: php, yii

i have following array values, here spend is repeated,

```
$array = array('Spend','Spend','Form Conversions','Phone Conversions')
```

i can detect multiple entries like this

```
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

output is

```
Array
(
   [Spend] => 2
   [Form Conversions] => 1
   [Phone Conversions] => 1
)
```

how can i put separate condition to print as follows

```
if(any key(here spend) found with count = 2 )
{
echo $duplicate element; //edits
}
else
{
 echo $no_duplicate_elements //edits
echo "count = 1 (here Form Conversions,Phone Conversions)";
}
```

Comment: you need to loop over key i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about

```
foreach(array_count_values($array) as $value => $count){
    if($count > 1){
        echo "hi " . $value . "*";
    }else{
       echo "count = 1 " . $value . "*";
    }
}
```

?

Comment: I don't see a change in the question - but `$value` is the key, so the output will be: `hi Spend*count = 1 Form Conversions*count = 1 Phone Conversions`

Answer (score 2):

use function in_array

```
if (in_array(2, array_count_values($array))) {
    echo "there is at least one word with count = 2";
}
```

if you want to know what elements are duplicated, then you have to use foreach - check **Jameson the dog**'s answer.

Comment: Wow, haven't thought of this. Awsome!

Comment: how to display the duplicate element..i have edited question please look in if condition